# How to resize the UIBarButtonItem , width doesn't seem to working

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

```
@IBOutlet var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

barButton.image = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

barButton.width = 50
```

still it gives a big gap so the user can press on the right side of the button and the button gets pressed. I am trying to resize the `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically . I have three buttons on the `rightBarButtonItem`

[image: bar button position]

Comment: are you using `UIToolBar`

Comment: these are the ones i'm using UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate

Comment: i mean where you placed your `UIBarButtonItem` .. in other words, super view of your `UIBarButtonItem` ?

Comment: hi i have added the image in the question for the bar button . However when i resize it using image insets nothing happens so I need help on how to do it programmatically